# How can I make my image scrollable? [Android Platform]

Tags: android, image, scroll

I have an image that takes up a lot more space than the android screen. I want the image to be presented full size and the user can move in any direction. Like a map.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tutorial I saw that did what you are describing
http://www.anddev.org/scrolling_a_picture_horizontally_and_vertically-t3245.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use a webview which gives this to you for free. I'm not sure why but when I tried
using the loadData method it didn't work, but using loadDataWithBaseURL with a null URL did.

With a webview your image can even be embedded in HTML. In the example below `yourContent` is simply a string.

E.g.

```
yourView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Can you send some sode that can do so using bitmap tranferred from server?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your image in an **ImageView** and wrap it using a **ScrollView** and a **HorizontalScrollView** like below.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/yourImage"/>

    </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

So you can scroll it horizontally and vertically like a map.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put scroll into xml layout with your image