# how to scroll the image in android layout?

Tags: android, layout, scroll

how to scroll the images in android layout when i run that program and when i click the  image in the scroll view it get zoom.

Answer (score 0):

[Rich image scroll and zooming on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015167/rich-image-scroll-and-zooming-on-android)

[How can I make my image scrollable? [Android Platform]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738018/how-can-i-make-my-image-scrollable-android-platform)

hope these helps

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thre is also another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images) with an answer from me that explains how to use a WebView to load an image. The webview will then do all the scrolling and zooming for you.